# how to find self intersection in a polygon using boost/?

Tags: boost, polygon, computational-geometry, boost-geometry, set-intersection

i need to find self intersections in a polygon.
i know boost has that ability.
but i can't figure out how to use the turn_info to get the information about the intersections. like what segments intersected and etc. 
can anyone help?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, properly, because the concepts defined by Boost Geometry dis-allow self intersections.

However, indirectly you can then use the validation features (new since I think 1.59) to get some information about self intersection:

```
std::string reason;
poly p;
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0, 0 4, 2 4, 2 2, 6 2, 6 6, 2 6, 2 4, 0 4, 0 8, 8 8, 8 0, 0 0))", expected);
bool ok = bg::is_valid(p, reason);
std::cout << "Expected: " << bg::dsv(p) << (ok?" valid":" invalid: '" + reason + "'") << "\n";
```

Prints:

> Expected: (((0, 0), (0, 4), (2, 4), (2, 2), (6, 2), (6, 6), (2, 6), (2, 4), (0, 4), (0, 8), (8, 8), (8, 0), (0, 0))) invalid: 'Geometry has invalid self-intersections. A self-intersection point was found at (0, 4); method: t; operations: x/u; segment IDs {source, multi, ring, segment}: {0, -1, -1, 0}/{0, -1, -1, 7}'

Comment: I suddenly realize I assumed [tag:boost-geometry]. I'm not that acquainted with [tag:boost-polygon] so if that's the context, my answer might not be accurate.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the response.i know for sure that you can find self intersections in a polygon.as i have seen a code that does it. i just don't remember how. i think there was a use of turn_info. but i'm getting lost over there. if you know how to use the get turn_info maybe that could help.

Comment: I've actually spotted a post on the Boost Geometry mailing list where ... ironically Adam Wulkiewicz says "I saw in other email that you already figured it out.". I really think it's time for you to put some links to that here, even self-answering - it's a usefule Q&A really. As it is, you're consciously risking people spinning wheels wasting time for you after you have already figured things out.

Comment: IMHO It's not nice to have others run around after you to point out these hints for others, where you could easily take care of it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

So this is the code for getting the self intersections.

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
  using namespace std;
  typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_2d;
  typedef bg::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > Polygon;

  Polygon poly { { { 10, 10 }, { 20, 10 }, { 20, 5 }, { 25, 5 }, { 25, 7 }, { 30, 7 }, { 30, 3 }, { 25, 3 }, { 25, 5 }, { 20, 5 }, { 20, 0 }, { 10, 0 }, { 10, 10 } }};


  typedef bg::point_type<Polygon>::type point_type;
  typedef boost::geometry::detail::overlay::turn_info<point_type, boost::geometry::segment_ratio<double> > TurnInfoType;

  bg::detail::no_rescale_policy robust_policy;
  bg::detail::self_get_turn_points::no_interrupt_policy interrupt_policy;
  std::vector<TurnInfoType> turns;

 boost::geometry::self_turns<boost::geometry::detail::overlay::assign_null_policy>(poly.outer(), robust_policy, turns, interrupt_policy);
```

for getting the info just use something like:

```
turns[i].operations[0].seg_id.segment_index
```